# Как редактировать "штампы" в PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Снимок экрана]

Как вы видите после написания точки появляются некие "штампы". Да именно штампы, а не live templates (main не считается - он мимо проходил). И мне бы хотелось добавить несколько своих шаблонов. Подскажите как это можно реализовать и по возможности документации с ключевыми словами ну, что-то навроде выражение - expr как видно ниже. Заранее - спасибо.

p.s. Все настройки просмотрел, но нигде не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заходим в **Settings | Plugins** и устанавливаем плагин "Custom Postfix Templates"
2. Читаем [документацию](https://github.com/xylo/intellij-postfix-templates#custom-postfix-templates-for-intellij-idea)
3. Заходим в **Settings | Editor | Custom Postfix Templates**
4. Создаем файл в любой удобной директории с расширением ".postfixTemplates"
5. Пишем свои  postfix-ы и сохраняем
6. Добавляем файл  и нажимаем кнопку "Update now"
7. Радуемся тому, что теперь мы можем оптимизировать процесс написания кода

Answer (score 4):

Это "postfix completion". См. **Preferences/Settings | Editor | General | Postfix Completion**. Добавление новых для Python пока, к сожалению, не поддерживается (тикет [PY-30217](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30217/Allow-creation-of-custom-postfix-templates-for-Python)).

Comment: Да, но оказывается есть плагин, который позволяет это реализовать :)